# Ionic 2 segment not working with Angular directives

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

i trying to create dynamic generated Ionic 2 segment buttons, but everytime when i use some of Angular directives, it fail. I see segments buttons, but click doesnt change anything including ngModel variable. See example:

Working static example:

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="subsActiveDay">
    <ion-segment-button value="2016-03-01T00:00:00.000Z">
        1
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="2016-03-02T00:00:00.000Z">
    2
    </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
{{subsActiveDay}}
```

Not working:

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="subsActiveDay">
    <ion-segment-button *ngFor="#day of subs" [value]="day.date">
        {{day.datestamp | date}}
    </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
{{subsActiveDay}}
```

In second example buttons are generated, but there is no default selected button and subsActiveDay variable doesn't change after click. I tried to figure out ngFor and use two test variables defined in component for value, but result was fail too.

Any ideas where could be problem?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, did you find the solution yet?

Comment: Unfortunately, no :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found the workaround after viewing the segment source code. So you can just use `value` instead of `[value]` like this:

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="subsActiveDay">
    <ion-segment-button *ngFor="#day of subs" value="{{day.date}}">
        {{day.datestamp | date}}
    </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
{{subsActiveDay}}
```

There is a line that check whether the `value` attribute is presented when `ngOnInit` or not at line 98 in segment.js like this

```
SegmentButton.prototype.ngOnInit = function () {
    if (!util_1.isPresent(this.value)) {
```

Hope this can help you.